# How to get date of yesterday with the time part 00:00:00 in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In big query how do I get the yesterday date with the time part 00:00:00?

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? Show us some code, some effort!

Answer (score 1):

DATE Doesn't have time part
if you want yesterday DateTime with 00:00 as time use:

```
SELECT DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), DAY) as yesterday;
```

if you want yesterday date use:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as yesterday;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a time part, then you want either a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column.

So, either:

```
SELECT DATETIME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) as yesterday_dt,
       TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) as yesterday_ts
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gets you date

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()));
```

For different methods check this link

[MS SQL Server - How to get Date only from the datetime value?](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/ms-sql-server-how-to-get-date-only-from-datetime-value.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is yet another option for BigQuery standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(86400 * (UNIX_DATE(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1)) yesterday_as_timestamp,
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(86400 * (UNIX_DATE(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1))) yesterday_as_datetime
```

with result (as of answer day - April 02, 2019)

```
Row     yesterday_as_timestamp      yesterday_as_datetime    
1       2019-04-01 00:00:00 UTC     2019-04-01T00:00:00
```

Note:

```
DATETIME    Represents a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and subsecond. Range: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999.   
TIMESTAMP   Represents an absolute point in time, with microsecond precision.   Range: 0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC.
```

> A timestamp represents an absolute point in time, independent of any time zone or convention such as Daylight Savings Time.
>
> TIMESTAMP provides microsecond precision.
>
> Unlike Timestamps, a DATETIME object does not refer to an absolute instance in time. Instead, it is the civil time, or the time that a user would see on a watch or calendar.

You can see more details about DATETIME and TIMESTAMP in [Data Types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) doc